# Github action cannot get secret when using container

Tags: docker, github, containers

Currently, I am using docker to run to job and trying to pass secrets to docker env. However, when I print out the env, it is blank instead of *****.
github version is GitHub Enterprise Server 3.6.3

```
  npm-build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    container: 
      image: node:16
      env:
        NPM_AUTH: ${{ secrets.NPM_AUTH }}
```

I tried pass plaintext and it can pass into the env.
I expect the secret can pass into the docker env

Comment: hi there can you provide details